# How do I find multiples values in binary search algorithm

Tags: c, binary-search

I want find many values in a binary search the problem is the binary search just find the first one and return it. Can I find as many I want? For example imagine that I have this input:

```
00001 1521065760 38 42' 50" -9 8' 22"
00001 1521066360 38 42' 4" -9 45' 24"
00001 1521066960 38 41' 18" -9 22' 26"
00001 1521067560 38 40' 32" -8 59' 28"
00001 1521068160 38 39' 46" -8 36' 30"
00001 1521068760 38 39' 2" -8 13' 32"
00001 1521069360 38 34' 0" -7 54' 0"
00001 1521069960 38 34' 0" -7 54' 0"
00002 1521065760 38 10' 33" -8 41' 35"
00002 1521066360 38 16' 14" -8 35' 36"
00002 1521066960 38 21' 55" -8 30' 20"
00002 1521067560 38 27' 36" -8 24' 44"
00002 1521068160 38 33' 17" -8 19' 8"
00002 1521068760 38 39' 2" -8 13' 32"
00002 1521069360 38 37' 16" -8 4' 50"
00002 1521069960 38 34' 0" -7 54' 0"
```

I want to find using binary search where 'codigos'(id) differents has the same input  so it will be return this values(00001 and 00002):

```
   1521068760 38 39' 2" -8 13' 32"
   1521069960 38 34' 0" -7 54' 0"
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct suspeito{
   int codigo;
   int instante;
   int graulatitude;
   int minutolatitude;
   int segundolatitude;
   int graulongitude;
   int minutolongitude;
   int segundolongitude;
   };

  int PesquisaBinaria(int n, struct suspeito informacao[], int i, int j)
   {
     if (i > j)
        return -1;                  // o intervalo i..j Ã© vazio

    int m = (i + j) / 2;          // ponto mÃ©dio do intervalo

    if (n < informacao[m].codigo)
        // restringe a pesquisa ao intervalo i..m - 1
         return PesquisaBinaria(n, informacao, i, m - 1);

    if (n > informacao[m].codigo)
          // restringe a pesquisa ao intervalo m + 1..j
         return PesquisaBinaria(n, informacao, m + 1, j);

      // n == v[m]
    return m;
          } 
    int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
    {
     const struct suspeito *elem1 = (struct suspeito *)p1;
     const struct suspeito *elem2 = (struct suspeito *)p2;
     if (elem1->codigo < elem2->codigo)
         return -1;
     else if (elem1->codigo > elem2->codigo)
         return 1;
     else
         return 0;
       }
   int main()
      {


      struct suspeito informacao[10000];
        int codigo,instante,graulatitude,minutolatitude,segundolatitude,graulongitude,minutolongitude,segundolongitude;
int count,par1,par2;
while(1) {
    scanf(" %d",&codigo);
    if(codigo==0) {
        break;
    }
    scanf(" %d %d %d\' %d\" %d %d\' %d\"",&instante,&graulatitude,&minutolatitude,&segundolatitude,&graulongitude,&minutolongitude,&segundolongitude);
    informacao[count].codigo=codigo;
    informacao[count].instante=instante;
    informacao[count].graulatitude=graulatitude;
    informacao[count].minutolatitude=minutolatitude;
    informacao[count].segundolatitude=segundolatitude;
    informacao[count].graulongitude=graulongitude;
    informacao[count].minutolongitude=minutolongitude;
    informacao[count].segundolongitude=segundolongitude;
    count++;
}
qsort(informacao,count,sizeof(informacao[0]),compare);
printf("Codigo: %d\nInstante: %d\n",informacao[3].codigo,informacao[3].instante);

if(codigo==00000) {
    while(scanf(" %d %d",&par1,&par2)!=EOF) {
            int find1=PesquisaBinaria(par1,informacao,0,count);
            int find2=PesquisaBinaria(par2,informacao,0,count);
            if(find1==-1 && find2!=-1)
                printf("+ sem dados sobre o suspeito %d",par1);
            if(find1!=-1 && find2==-1)
                printf("+ sem dados sobre o suspeito %d",par2);
            if(find1!=-1 && find2!=-1) {
                printf("Index1:%d \nIndex2:%d\n",find1-1,find2-1);
                printf("Codigo1:%d\nInstante1:%d\nGrauLatitude1:%d\nMinutoLatitude1:%d\nSegundoLatitude1:%d\nGrauLongitude1:%d\nMinutoLongitude1:%d\nSegundoLongitude1:%d\n",informacao[find1-1].codigo,informacao[find1-1].instante,informacao[find1-1].graulatitude,informacao[find1-1].minutolatitude,informacao[find1-1].segundolatitude,informacao[find1-1].graulongitude,informacao[find1-1].minutolongitude,informacao[find1-1].segundolongitude);
                printf("Codigo2:%d\nInstante2:%d\nGrauLatitude2:%d\nMinutoLatitude2:%d\nSegundoLatitude2:%d\nGrauLongitude2:%d\nMinutoLongitude2:%d\nSegundoLongitude2:%d\n",informacao[find2-1].codigo,informacao[find2-1].instante,informacao[find2-1].graulatitude,informacao[find2-1].minutolatitude,informacao[find2-1].segundolatitude,informacao[find2-1].graulongitude,informacao[find2-1].minutolongitude,informacao[find2-1].segundolongitude);
                if(informacao[find1-1].instante==informacao[find2-1].instante && informacao[find1-1].graulatitude == informacao[find2-1].graulatitude && informacao[find1-1].minutolatitude==informacao[find2-1].minutolatitude && informacao[find1-1].segundolatitude == informacao[find2-1].segundolatitude && informacao[find1-1].graulongitude==informacao[find2-1].graulongitude && informacao[find1-1].minutolongitude==informacao[find2-1].minutolongitude && informacao[find1-1].segundolongitude==informacao[find2-1].segundolongitude)
                    printf("+ %05d e %05d podem ter-se encontrado em:\n",par1,par2);

            }
    }
    }



   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `bsearch()` library function.
However, it returns an arbitrary object and not the first match.
You may then iterate from the bsearch result backwards to find the first element. In principle (using `char *` instead of `void *` to have simpler code) this could look like:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

    char * bsearch_first(char * key, char * arr, 
                         size_t cnt, size_t size, 
                         int(*cmp)(const void *, const void *)); 
    {
         char * result = bsearch(key,arr,cnt,size,cmp);

         if ( NULL != result ) {
             while ( arr < result && cmp(key, result - size) ) {
                 result -= size;
             }
         }
         return result;   
    }
```

Another approach is to implement that bsearch variant from scratch.

Then iterate all elements starting `bsearch_first()` until `cmp() != 0` or the end if the array is reached:

```
    for ( item = bsearch_first(key,arr, ...);
          NULL != item 
            && item < (BYTE*)arr + sizeof arr
            && 0 == cmp(key,item);
          ++item )
    {
         do_stuff_with(item);
    }
```

Comment: oops! `char*` intead of `BYTE*`.